# Which Sentence is correct?(comparison of adjectives)

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions

I am going to write a sentence including the word "height". It must mean that one thing is as high as the other one. Which Sentence is true?

1. "A" has as much height as "B".
2. The height of "A" is as much as the height of "B".

If you have better alternatives, I would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Why must you use the word "height"?

Comment: A and B are the same height.

Comment: Please don't use "true" to mean "correct". These are two different words that mean two different things. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks ЯegDwight  for your important remark.

Comment: I have seen this in an English exam Hot Licks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the "as...as..." construction, it is better to say A is as high as B (is). If you must use the word "height", it seems that you are comparing their accurate heights mathematically. I would prefer "A's height is equal to B's" or "They have the same height."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the word height, you can say that A and B are at the same height or A and B have the same height but if you want to use the phrase as...as, the first thing you should consider is what is the real nature of A and B. If A and B are non living things, I think you should use A is as high as B. Then if A and B represent people here you use tall instead of high or height. A is as tall as B.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking only about grammar, both sentences are grammatical. Neither, however, is at all idiomatic in American English.

As Danniel Wang said,

> A is the same height as B

or

> A and B have the same height

are far more idiomatic. Moreover, using the adjective “high” is probably the most idiomatic, particularly in speech, e.g.

> A is as high as B

or

> A and B are equally high